# Displaying text in texbox from databse based on selected items from combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have basically a combobox and a text box.

The combobox consists of subject code, whereas the textbox consists of a subject name which is stored in the database.

Is there any way that when an item from combobox is selected, it automatically displays the subject name based on the selected subject code, which will be from the database?

Below is my code, but it is not working.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select subject_code from subjectinfo", con);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        oda1.Fill(dt1);
        comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.DataSource = dt1;
        comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.DisplayMember = "subject_code";
        comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.SelectedIndex = -1;
        con.Close();

    }

    private void comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = "select subject_abbreviation from subjectinfo where subject_code ='" + comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.Text + "'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);

        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr["subject_abbreviation"].ToString();//column name should be that you want to show on textbox

        }

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the selectedindex changed event of your combobox.

Comment: I hope this is test code, as it is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: thanks for the reply, how can i do that, is there any reference that would like to share to see on using the selectedindex change event on combobox. Yup this is the test code.. Later i will adjust it to avoid sql injection

Comment: i tried but not working too

Comment: Why is it not working ? Do you get an error ? Or you get an unexpected result ?

Comment: what i am getting is problem is
1) since i set [comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.SelectedIndex = -1;], the combobox is correct showing empty string but the textbox showing the value of [comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.SelectedIndex = 0;] which is in the databse instead of showing empty
2) when i drop the the list in combobox to show and select different item an error is showing which indicating [ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.]